# HTML Canvas Graphics Some things not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**This Text is a dummy plz avoid this. plz focus on last line on this paragraph. Thank you
Note: Always specify an id attribute (to be referred to in a script), and a width and height attribute to define the size of the canvas. To add a border, use the style attribute.**

HTML Canvas Graphics This code does not work for me, anyone can solve this error.

```
<html>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>


var c = document.getElementById("myCanva");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

 
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(75,50,5,90,60,100);
grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
grd.addColorStop(1,"white");


ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(10,10,150,80);


</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Typo: document.getElementById("myCanva"); -> document.getElementById("myCanva**s**");

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is because the canvas id that you call `myCanvas` is not the same as your `getElementById`, and that has the id `myCanva`. i am sure this is not intentional and it works on my end if you change `myCanva` to `myCanvas`.